# How do you differentiate the use of "When I asked..." and "When I have asked..."

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, present-tense, perfect-aspect

This might be a very basic question for native speakers of English, but I'd really appreciate if you could help me to understand the difference between "When I asked" and "When I have asked...".

In the example passage below, the author uses "When I have asked..." but I somehow feel "When I asked" is more natural.

> In my opinion, true friendship is devoid of self-interest. **When I have asked** my friends to do something for me, I have hardly ever done so just for my own benefit or in order to make any material gain. I am satisfied just to observe that we enjoy each other's company and that they are happy to associate with me.

I'd really appreciate it if you could explain the difference and possibly provide some example sentences that can show the difference in the usage.

Thank you for your time, in advance.
HK

Comment: _When I asked my friends to do something for me_ would imply that you were referring to one particular occasion. The paragraph is talking about multiple occasions. _When I have [done so]_ in this context means _every time in the past that I [did so]._

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response to my question. Your explanation makes perfect sense to me and now I feel I can use them accordingly in my writing.